# Kalanchoe issues. Leggy, yellowing leaves, etc

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, kalanchoe

I've had this kalanchoe for a year and a half and it was doing great until a couple months ago. It started getting very tall, almost etiolated with all the bottom leaves dying. I was likely watering it too much so cut back a few weeks ago, no luck. The leaves aren't waxy and thick like they were, they got very soft soft and thin. I thought the etiolation meant more sunlight needed, but I've read direct sunlight can be an issue as well. I recently repotted it with loose soil. Should I move it?

Another interesting point. My partner and I each got one of these plants at the same time, same place. Her's looks exactly the same as when we bought it, but with larger and thicker leaves. Mine grew like crazy and is now doing wild things! [image]

*Long-time lurker, first time poster. I checked all over and didn't see a question quite like this about a leggy kalanchoe. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.